# Boton cerrar en un div con video

Tags: html, bootstrap

Como colocar el boton de cerrar, lo siento no se mucho de diseño por eso uso bootstrap. este es la imagen de mi sistema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="videos"  role="dialog"
                 aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <video autoplay width="1080" height="720" controls>
                    <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dist/video/hola.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                </video>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

puedes cerrar tu modal, te sugiero meterlo en un `modal-header`, y tu vídeo en un `modal-body`, para que sea mas sencillo de manejar

se vería algo así:

```
    <div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>                       
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">    
                    <video autoplay width="100%" controls>
                           <source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dist/video/hola.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
                           Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                     </video>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: todo se descuadra :c

Comment: @IvanMoreFlores ok, si ya veo, es por el tamaño de tu vídeo usa width="100%", actualizo la respuesta